# Getting Current Child ID from TableViewCell row to Another View Controller and Update this Child ID with adding new fields

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the below codes. Database Tree, Customer Class, CustomerAddViewController, CustomerViewController and OrderAddViewController. I want to get the customers child key as shown in Database Tree from CustomerViewController tableview row when clicked the row and forward it to  OrderAddViewController and update the correct selected row's customer key, and generate a new Order Key with new fields as in the OrderAddViewController as shown in the Database Tree.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I can forward the customer child key to OrderAddViewController as CustomerKey but i cannot write the order fields to correct customer child key. How can i do this?

Database Tree:

```
    -Customers
       -L9foIoskS8pOdKVI8BN <----- Customers Child Key
            -created by: "Test Test"
            -created by id: "khfRNU9vDTXSUqH5ArZhStzEmEr1"
            -customer address: "ABC"
            -customer id: "-L9foIoskS8pOdKVI8BN"
            -customer name: "Test 11"
            -customer phone: "0123456789"
            -customer reference: "XYZ"
            -customer school name: "DEF"
            -customer type: "Customer Type A"
            -timestamp: "10.04.2018 01:13:44"
--------->  - I want to add a new Uniq ID here and add Order Details under this  like below
                -order period: 
                -order id:
                -order school name:
                -order name:
                -order girl count:
                -order boy count:
                -order shoes count:
                -order delivery date:
                -order return date:
                -order created by:
                -order created by id:
                -timestamp:
       -L9gSIWPcWnWdkl2kPUx
            -created by: "Test Test"
            -created by id: "khfRNU9vDTXSUqH5ArZhStzEmEr1"
            -customer address: "ABC"
            -customer id: "-L9gSIWPcWnWdkl2kPUx"
            -customer name: "Test 12"
            -customer phone: "0123456789"
            -customer reference: "XYZ"
            -customer school name: "DEF"
            -customer type: "Customer Type A"
            -timestamp: "10.04.2018 01:13:44"
```

Customer.swift

```
import UIKit

class Customer: NSObject {

    var customertype: String?
    var customerid: String?
    var customername: String?
    var customerphone: String?
    var customerreference: String?
    var customerschoolname: String?
    var customeraddress: String?
}
```

CustomerAddViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CustomerAddViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var customertypeField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var customernametextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var customerphonetextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var customerreferencetextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var customerschooltextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var customeraddresstextField: UITextField!

    let customertypes = ["Hoca", "Tek", "Kargo"]
    var customertypepickerView = UIPickerView()

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customertypepickerView.delegate = self
        customertypepickerView.dataSource = self
        customertypeField.inputView = customertypepickerView
        customertypeField.textAlignment = .center

        ref = Database.database().reference()

    }

    @IBAction func cancelBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let key = ref.child("Customers").childByAutoId().key

        guard customernametextField.text != "", customerphonetextField.text != ""  else {return}

        let date = Date()
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        let timestamp = df.string(from: date)

        let CustomerInfo: [String: Any] = ["customer type" : self.customertypeField.text!,
                                           "customer id" : key,
                                           "customer name" : self.customernametextField.text!,
                                           "customer phone": self.customerphonetextField.text!,
                                           "customer reference": self.customerreferencetextField.text!,
                                           "customer school name":self.customerschooltextField.text!,
                                           "customer address":customeraddresstextField.text!,
                                           "created by" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName!,
                                           "created by id" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid,
                                           "timestamp": timestamp]

        self.ref.child("Customers").child(key).setValue(CustomerInfo)
        print(self.customernametextField.text! + " - Customer created.")

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return customertypes.count

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return customertypes[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        customertypeField.text = customertypes[row]
        customertypeField.resignFirstResponder()

        if customertypeField.text != "Hoca" {
            customerreferencetextField.isHidden = false
            customerschooltextField.isHidden = false
            customeraddresstextField.isHidden = false
        } else {
            customerreferencetextField.isHidden = true
            customerschooltextField.isHidden = true
            customeraddresstextField.isHidden = true

        }

    }
}
```

CustomerViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CustomerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var customertableview: UITableView!

    var customerList = [Customer]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        retrieveCustomers()

    }

    func retrieveCustomers() {

        Database.database().reference().child("Customers").queryOrdered(byChild: "customer type").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

            let customers = Customer()

            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let type = value["customer type"] as? String ?? "Customer Type not found."
                let id = value["customer id"] as? String ?? "Customer Type not found."
                let name = value["customer name"] as? String ?? "Customer Name not found."
                let phone = value["customer phone"] as? String ?? "Customer Phone not found."
                let reference = value["customer reference"] as? String ?? "Customer Reference not found."
                let school = value["customer school"] as? String ?? "Customer School Name not found."
                let address = value["customer address"] as? String ?? "Customer Address not found."
                customers.customertype = type
                customers.customerid = id
                customers.customername = name
                customers.customerphone = phone
                customers.customerreference = reference
                customers.customerschoolname = school
                customers.customeraddress = address
                self.customerList.append(customers)
            }
            self.customertableview.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return customerList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath ) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomerCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomerTableViewCell

        let customers = customerList[indexPath.row]
        cell?.nametextField.text = customers.customername
        cell?.phonetextField.text = customers.customerphone
        cell?.typetextField.text = customers.customertype
        return cell!
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "CustomerToOrder") {
            if let indexPath = self.customertableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let orderAddVC:OrderAddViewController = segue.destination as! OrderAddViewController
                let story = customerList[indexPath.row]
                orderAddVC.CustomerKey = [story.customerid as! String]
        }
        }
    }
}
```

OrderAddViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class OrderAddViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var orderperiodtextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var schoolnametextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ordernametextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var girlcounttextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var boycounttextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var shoestextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var orderdeliverydatetextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var orderreturndatetextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var notetextField: UITextField!

    let orderperiod = ["Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran"]
    var orderperiodpickerView = UIPickerView()

    var CustomerKey:[String] = []

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(CustomerKey)

        orderperiodpickerView.delegate = self
        orderperiodpickerView.dataSource = self
        orderperiodtextField.inputView = orderperiodpickerView
        orderperiodtextField.textAlignment = .center

        ref = Database.database().reference()

    }

    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let key = ref.child("Customers").childByAutoId().key

        let date = Date()
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        let timestamp = df.string(from: date)

        let OrderInfo: [String: Any] = ["order period" : self.orderperiodtextField.text!,
                                        "order id" : key,
                                        "order school name" : self.schoolnametextField.text!,
                                        "order name": self.ordernametextField.text!,
                                        "order girl count": self.girlcounttextField.text!,
                                        "order boy count":self.boycounttextField.text!,
                                        "order shoes count":self.shoestextField.text!,
                                        "order delivery date":self.orderdeliverydatetextField.text!,
                                        "order return date":self.orderreturndatetextField.text!,
                                        "order created by" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName!,
                                        "order created by id" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid,
                                        "timestamp": timestamp]

        self.ref.updateChildValues(["/Customers/\(key)/": OrderInfo])
        print(self.ordernametextField.text! + " - Order created.")

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return orderperiod.count

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return orderperiod[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        orderperiodtextField.text = orderperiod[row]
        orderperiodtextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If i change the code as below, the error message is "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type String".

let key = ref.child("Customers").child(CustomerKey).childByAutoId().key
If i only change the below code, then application is crashed with this reason. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(updateChildValues:) Invalid key in object. Keys must be non-empty and cannot contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

self.ref.updateChildValues(["/Customers/(CustomerKey)/(key)/": OrderInfo])
With CustomerAddViewController i am already creating the database tree as below

```
-Customers
   -L9foIoskS8pOdKVI8BN <----- Customers Child Key
        -created by: "Test Test"
        -created by id: "khfRNU9vDTXSUqH5ArZhStzEmEr1"
        -customer address: "ABC"
        -customer id: "-L9foIoskS8pOdKVI8BN"
        -customer name: "Test 11"
        -customer phone: "0123456789"
        -customer reference: "XYZ"
        -customer school name: "DEF"
        -customer type: "Customer Type A"
        -timestamp: "10.04.2018 01:13:44"
```

--------->  - This part need to be add when updated.
                -order period: 
                -order id:
                -order school name:
                -order name:
                -order girl count:
                -order boy count:
                -order shoes count:
                -order delivery date:
                -order return date:
                -order created by:
                -order created by id:
                -timestamp: 
I need to update the database tree with OrderAddViewController but I think forwarding the CustomerKey is wrong or this technic is wrong. But i didnt find a good way to click the row from tableview and then update the selected table via OrderAddViewController.

Comment: The error "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type String". Is telling you the error. You made CustomerKey a string array not a String. Change it to a string like I suggest below or user CustomerKey[0]. To get the only String in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
self.ref.updateChildValues(["/Customers/\(key)/": OrderInfo])
```

You're telling Firebase to write the data to Customers -> Key you just created.

**You want Customers -> CustomerKey -> Key.**

**Update**

In `class OrderAddViewController:` change `var CustomerKey:[String] = []` to `var customerKey:String?`

In `class CustomerAddViewController` update  `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` so that you just pass the customer id String.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "CustomerToOrder") {
            if let indexPath = self.customertableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let orderAddVC:OrderAddViewController = segue.destination as! OrderAddViewController
                if let customerId = customerList[indexPath.row].customerid {
                    orderAddVC.customerKey = customerId
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I recommend the following change:

```
self.ref.updateChildValues(["/Customers/\(key)/": OrderInfo])
```

Should be

```
self.ref.updateChildValues(["/Customers/-L9foIoskS8pOdKVI8BN/\(key)/": OrderInfo])
```

using the passed variable we get

```
self.ref.updateChildValues(["/Customers/\(customerId!)/\(key)/": OrderInfo])
```

Not sure if this matters but you also might want to change:

```
let key = ref.child("Customers").childByAutoId().key
```

To:

```
let key = ref.child("Customers").child(customerId!).childByAutoId().key
```

Based on your comments it looks like your original `CustomerKey` is a String array so you can probably pass the desired string value by using `CustomerKey[0]`

Hope this helps...

Comment: I updated with a new answer post, error details and tried to explane the issue

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the comments and answer posted below. Please delete your answers and update your original question.

Comment: wow you done this. I'm really appreciated for your kind help. I just only want to update something you wrote.
From:
`let key = ref.child("Customers").child(customerId!).childByAutoId().key`
To:
`let key = ref.child("Customers").child(CustomerKey!).childByAutoId().key`